# SIM800L GSM Module working with http and shows error with https, why?

Tags: ssl, arduino, ssl-certificate, gsm

I'm trying to send some sensor data to MySQL database using Arduino and sim800l GSM module. And it's working perfectly when I use HTTP for the URL and remove the SSL certificate from my website. But when I have enabled the SSL certificate on my website it shows HTTP response code 606 in the serial monitor.
Here is my working code without SSL certificate(this code works perfectly)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(3, 2);

void setup()
{
  gprsSerial.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(19200);

  Serial.println("Config SIM900...");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Done!...");
  gprsSerial.flush();
  Serial.flush();

  // attach or detach from GPRS service 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
  delay(100);
  toSerial();


  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"myapn\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
   gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1");
   delay(2000);
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
}


void loop()
{
   // initialize http service
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
   delay(2000); 
   toSerial();

   // set http param value
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://www.website123456.com/data/index.php?data1=2.88&data2=2.93\""); 
   delay(20000);
   toSerial();

   // set http action type 0 = GET, 1 = POST, 2 = HEAD
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
   delay(6000);
   toSerial();

   // read server response
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD"); 
   delay(10000);
   toSerial();

   gprsSerial.println("");
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
   toSerial();
   delay(300);

   gprsSerial.println("");
   delay(10000);
}

void toSerial()
{
  while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)
  {
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
  }
}
```

Here is the output when I replace the URL with https and enable my website ssl. (as you can see it shows http response code 606 "Not Acceptable
The user's agent was contacted successfully but some aspects of the session description such as the requested media, bandwidth, or addressing style were not acceptable"

```
23:16:48.974 -> Config SIM800L...
23:16:50.946 -> Done!...
23:16:51.079 -> AT+CGATT?

23:16:51.079 -> +CGATT: 1
23:16:51.079 -> 
23:16:51.079 -> OK
23:16:53.107 -> AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

23:16:53.107 -> OK
23:16:55.100 -> AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","dialogbb"

23:16:55.133 -> OK
23:16:59.122 -> AT+SAPBR=0,1

23:16:59.155 -> OK
23:16:59.155 -> AT+SAPBR=1,1

23:17:01.151 -> OK
23:17:03.185 -> AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://www.mywebsitttte.com/index.php?dAT+HTTPSSL=1

23:17:08.207 -> OK
23:17:14.221 -> AT+HTTPACTION=0

23:17:14.255 -> OK
23:17:14.255 -> 
23:17:14.255 -> +HTTPACTION: 0,606,0
23:17:24.266 -> AT+HTTPREAD

23:17:24.266 -> OK
23:17:36.595 -> 
AT+HTTPTERM

23:17:36.595 -> OK
```

So what are the modifications I should do to this code, to be able to upload data to the website with SSL certificate? I have seen people say I need to enter to SSL mode using this code `AT+HTTPSSL=1`  where should I put this code. Thanks

Comment: On a small 8bit Arduino, you should simply forget about SSL.

Comment: But it shows an error when I have SSL on the website. I don't need ssl for this data sending process, but i need ssl for the website

Comment: `603 Decline :"The destination does not wish to participate in the call, or cannot do so"`
Hmm, so your question is: how to make the web server accept http requests (Port 80)

Comment: It's accepting the request when i send with https but not with https

Comment: @datafiddler The module should be handling encryption, not Arduino.

Comment: Why not use [a library](https://github.com/ostaquet/Arduino-SIM800L-driver) that handles all that AT command juggling in a proper way?

Comment: I don't want to complicate this. I just need to do this with https instead of http

Comment: When I use https instead of http in the arduino url, I'm getting http response code 606

Comment: The point of libraries is to abstract complex thing and make things less complicated.

Comment: facing the same issue on SIM800 . Did anyone find. any solution to this

Comment: @AshfaqHAhmed yes I have figured out it finally, It happens because this sim800 only supports TLS 1.0. But it's a deprecated version and many websites and host services have disabled it. You can check your server TLS version from here https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out it finally, It happens because this sim800 only supports TLS 1.0. But it's a deprecated version and many websites and host services have disabled it. You can check your server SSL version from here cdn77.com/tls-test

Answer (score 1):

Check your SIM800 firmware first, I had old firmware on my 808 module that had no SSL and I only bought it a few weeks ago. you can check using this AT command:

```
AT+HTTPSSL=?
```

If you get error then check and update the firmware.
Otherwise if working this is the order I use:

```
 client.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
 getresponse();
 delay(1000);
 client.println("AT+HTTPSSL=1");    // set SSL for HTTPS
 getresponse();
 delay(1000);
 client.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
 getresponse();
 delay(1000);
```

I can reliably HTTPS connect to my Firebase database.